# Wrong result, drawing a cube in SharpDX

Tags: c#, shader, directx-11, sharpdx, perspectivecamera

I want to draw a cube in SharpDX. And this is my current result:

[image: Cube]

As you can see, at some point, parts of the cube are cut.

[image: Cube2]

I don't know what setting is wrong, what could it be? I think it's something wrong with the perspective. I tried to create a perspective view, but i never got another result than an empty window.

Here is my code:

```
struct Vertex
{
    public Vector4 position;
    public Color4 color;
    //...
}

SharpDX.Direct3D11.Buffer vertexBuffer;
SharpDX.Direct3D11.Buffer projBuffer;

Matrix projMatrix;

Vertex[] vertices;
```

Init:

```
//...
BufferDescription description = new BufferDescription(sizeof(float) * 8 * vertices.Length, ResourceUsage.Dynamic, BindFlags.VertexBuffer, CpuAccessFlags.Write, ResourceOptionFlags.None, 0);
vertexBuffer = SharpDX.Direct3D11.Buffer.Create(Device, vertices, description);

//To pass projection matrix to shader
projBuffer = new SharpDX.Direct3D11.Buffer(Device, Matrix.SizeInBytes, ResourceUsage.Default, BindFlags.ConstantBuffer, CpuAccessFlags.None, ResourceOptionFlags.None, 0);
DeviceContext.VertexShader.SetConstantBuffer(1, projBuffer);
```

Update:

```
projMatrix = Matrix.OrthoOffCenterLH(-10, 10, -screenRatio*10, screenRatio*10, 1f, 100f);

//How can i create a perspective view?
//projMatrix = Matrix.PerspectiveFovLH(1f, (float)width/height, 1f, 100f);

projMatrix *= Matrix.Rotation...

DeviceContext.UpdateSubresource(ref projMatrix, projBuffer);
```

Shader:

```
struct VOut
{
  float4 position : SV_POSITION;
  float4 color    : COLOR;
};

cbuffer meshBuffer : register(b1)
{
  float4x4 projMatrix;
}

VOut VShader(float4 position : POSITION, float4 color : COLOR)
{
  VOut output;

  output.position = mul(position, projMatrix);
  output.color = color;

  return output;
}

float4 PShader(float4 position : SV_POSITION, float4 color : COLOR) : SV_TARGET
{
  return color;
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: (Guessing here) Is your back clipping plane too close?

Comment: @Alex I had `IsDepthClipEnabled = true` in my `RasterizerStateDescription`. i disabled it and now it works :) Do you also have a guess why i can't get an perspective view?

Comment: No, sorry. I've no experience with this package at all. In fact, I didn't even look at your code, I just took a guess based on the images you posted! :)

Comment: @fedab Try asking this on gamedev.stackexchange.com. The users there are more acquainted with game development libraries. That's not to say that someone here won't know the answer.

Comment: What are the vertex positions of your cube, and what are the transformations you apply prior to rendering?  An easy change that might work would be to change your ortho planes from (1,100) to (0.01,10000).  You'll want to tighten it up a bit eventually to avoid z-fighting, but it should get things rendering.

Comment: I don't use SharpDX, but in raw DX11 you would need to transpose your projection matrix before updating in the shader resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alex pointed out: There is something wrong with the clipping plane. I changed in my RasterizerStateDescription `IsDepthClipEnabled` to `false`. Then i had my full cube, but not with the right perspective.

My problem about the perspective view had multiple reasons. One reason was, that i didn't transposed the projection matrix (pointed out by Roger Rowland).

I asked [here (gamedev.stackexchange.com)](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/75335/drawing-cube-in-sharpdx-wrong-perspective) and:

The second one was, that i used some transformations after i set my perspective. That caused some weird deformations.

The third reason was, that i put wrong coordinates for the cube. The result was a wrong culling.